# Android Page curl / flip / turn animation between ACTIVITIES (NOT images)

Tags: android, xml, animation, page-curl, android-transitions

has anyone been able to simulate a 3d-ish page curl animation with an XML anim file?

I have seen multiple questions on this topic, but all the answers usually lead to links with source code for a 3d page curl library that is meant for animation between two views / images.

I need a page curl animation between activities!

I'm willing to settle for something as simple as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <alpha
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android://from right of screen to left of screen
        android://alpha=0 to alpha = 1 />
</set>
```

this example THEORETICALLY simulates flipping a page by fading away from the right. Any ideas on how to actually properly code the above example? Or any other suggestions on achieving a page curl animation between activities (Please do not point me to the harism or MysticGames library)

Comment: did you get an answer for your question ?!

Comment: @MohamedElnady No, I did not.